# Azure DevOps - Cannot see shared queries folder

Tags: azure-devops

I have several projects in Azure Devops

I am Project Collection Admin (org level) and project admin of this particular project. I have allow permissions for everything and the only other group I'm a member of is "Project valid users"

I am unable to see the Shared Queries folder and when I try to configure widgets that need a query I see none (not even my favorites)

In the org settings, I tried removing myself as project admin on this project and re-adding back, but still cannot see shared queries

Anyone got any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Double check your Permissions, all the settings and properties are correct, not just "I'm in Proj Admins Group": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/set-query-permissions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said in the comment, you should check your permissions of shared queries.

[image]

Make sure the permission is `allow`.
Check "**Project Collection Administrators**" and "**Project Administrators**". Last, search your **user account** and double check.

[image]